# How can I search a key containing '&' or '"' in CouchDB VIEW

Tags: couchdb

When I query like the following in CouchDB:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:5984/content/_design/names/_view/by_name?key=%22xxx&xxx%22"
```

It returns:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}.
```

And when I remove the '&' from the key, then it is OK.

Could you please tell me how can I search a name containing '&' in VIEW? Or is the '&' forbidden in CouchDB keys?

Thanks.

Encoding for '&' works. But how to deal with '"'(%22)? As we all konw, we have to quote the value when querying in CouchDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to encode the uri component. The encoding for `&` is `%26`.

curl supports --data-urlencode parameter to encode keys for you. So you can also try this

`curl -G -v  http://localhost:5984/content/_design/names/_view/by_name --data-urlencode 'key="some key text & other key text"'`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I try the following:     curl -X GET "localhost:5984/content/_design/names/_view/by_name?key=%22xxx%26xxx%22", it returns nothing. While it do have a document match the key xxx&xxx in couchdb.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you test again? It is working for me.

Comment: What about "%7E%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29_%2B%7B%7D%7C%3A%22%3C%3E_windows", it seems still not work. And it returns {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}. I can not figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Now my problem becomes, how to query a key with '"'(i.e. %22) in CouchDB VIEW.

Comment: Thank you for your great help, could you please give some advice again?

Comment: If you are having trouble encoding the urls you can just send a [post](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) request to the view.